# Finding subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with under some condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

> Let $S$ be the subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of all vectors forming an angle $ \leq 45^{\circ}$ with the vector $(1 , 0 , 1)^T.$

I have no idea how to approach this problem?

Is this the right approach, $S=\{X=(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid  X.(1,0,1) \leq ||X||.||(1,0,1)||.\cos45^{\circ}\}$

Comment: This should help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition

Comment: If $r = (x,y,z)^T$ belongs to $S$ then $ r \cdot (1, 0, 1)^T = x + z = \cos \theta \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} $.  Since you want $\theta \le 45^\circ$ , then you want $\cos \theta \ge \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and hence, the inequality becomes $$ \dfrac{(x + z)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2} \sqrt{2}} \ge \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$ which simplifies to $$ \dfrac{(x+z)^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 } \ge 1 $$ and finally you get  $$ y^2 \le 2 x z $$